# Making sage work with ipython

Tags: python, cython, jupyter-notebook, sage

I have downloaded and ran `make` to install `sage` but when I am trying to run the following code in `ipython notebook` and I get a lot of error messages since it can not import the methods of sage program properly:

```
%load_ext cythonmagic
```

and then

```
%%cython 

include "sage/gsl/gsl.pxi" 

cdef double do_callback(double x, void* params): 
    return (<MyCallback>params).eval(x) 

cdef class MyCallback: 
    cdef double a 
    def __init__(self, a): 
        self.a = a 
    cpdef double eval(self, double x): 
        print "eval", x, self.a * x * x 
        return self.a * x * x 
    def call_gsl(self): 
        cdef gsl_integration_workspace* w = 
gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000) 

        cdef gsl_function F 
        F.function = &do_callback 
        F.params = <void*>self 

        cdef double result, error 
        gsl_integration_qags (&F, 0, 1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error); 
        print result, error 

        gsl_integration_workspace_free(w)
```

The errors are :

```
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3bcbbcb051de> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic(u'cython', u'', u'include "sage/gsl/gsl.pxi" \n\ncdef double do_callback(double x, void* params): \n    (<MyCallback>params).eval(x) \n\ncdef class MyCallback: \n    cdef double a \n    def __init__(self, a): \n        self.a = a \n    cpdef double eval(self, double x): \n        print "eval", x, self.a * x * x \n        return self.a * x * x \n    def call_gsl(self): \n        cdef gsl_integration_workspace* w = \ngsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000) \n\n        cdef gsl_function F \n        F.function = &do_callback \n        F.params = <void*>self \n\n        cdef double result, error \n        gsl_integration_qags (&F, 0, 1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error); \n        print result, error \n\n        gsl_integration_workspace_free(w) ')

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2127             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2128             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2129                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2130             return result
   2131 

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/cythonmagic.pyc in cython(self, line, cell)

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    189     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    190     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 191         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    192 
    193         if callable(arg):

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/cythonmagic.pyc in cython(self, line, cell)
    242                     force = True,
    243                     )
--> 244                 build_extension.extensions = cythonize([extension], **opts)
    245             except CompileError:
    246                 return

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.pyc in cythonize(module_list, exclude, nthreads, aliases, quiet, force, exclude_failures, **options)
    692         quiet=quiet,
    693         exclude_failures=exclude_failures,
--> 694         aliases=aliases)
    695     deps = create_dependency_tree(ctx, quiet=quiet)
    696     build_dir = getattr(options, 'build_dir', None)

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.pyc in create_extension_list(patterns, exclude, ctx, aliases, quiet, exclude_failures)
    618             if module_name not in seen:
    619                 try:
--> 620                     kwds = deps.distutils_info(file, aliases, base).values
    621                 except Exception:
    622                     if exclude_failures:

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.pyc in distutils_info(self, filename, aliases, base)
    528 
    529     def distutils_info(self, filename, aliases=None, base=None):
--> 530         return (self.transitive_merge(filename, self.distutils_info0, DistutilsInfo.merge)
    531             .subs(aliases)
    532             .merge(base))

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Compiler/Main.pyc in find_include_file(self, filename, pos)
    217                                                include=True)
    218         if not path:
--> 219             error(pos, "'%s' not found" % filename)
    220         return path
    221 

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Compiler/Errors.pyc in error(position, message)
    165     #print "Errors.error:", repr(position), repr(message) ###
    166     if position is None:
--> 167         raise InternalError(message)
    168     err = CompileError(position, message)
    169     if DebugFlags.debug_exception_on_error: raise Exception(err) # debug

InternalError: Internal compiler error: 'sage/gsl/gsl.pxi' not found
```

Any thought that might help it works?

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am using `anaconda` on `ubuntu`!

Comment: there is a ppa to install sage on ubuntu, it may be a better option.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the problem is that I am not root in my pc and the computer administer doesn't install it.

Comment: ah ok does `./sage` work from bash?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham however I am running this command `sage -f python` in the sage folder to see whether it would solve the problem or not?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well I want to call sage module in a script and not the other way around!

Comment: ,yes I understand but if it did not install correctly I imagine  you won't be able to use it .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry I just started knowing about sage, so how could I test it has been installed properly or not? Is it straightforward to import sage in python or cython script?

Comment: how did you start the notebook?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `ipython notebook` command and also from inside sage the command `notebook()`.

Comment: does `sage -ipython notebook` work?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I got this error massage : python: `/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /software/sage-6.2-x86_64-Linux/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0)`.

Comment: when you run `sage -notebook` it works?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham after running `sage -f python` this command, sage doesn't work no longer because it seems it finds out that my `GLIBC` is incompatible with the python and now I faced another problem.

Comment: try compiling from source again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the IPython notebook inside of Sage myself, and I'm not a Cython expert, so take this with a grain of salt.  (Hopefully those who do and are will see this - there are more hanging out [here](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/).) However, I wouldn't be surprised if starting off with a `from sage.all import *` helps.  I don't know that one can just include a random header like you are trying to do.  It turns out that importing just little pieces of Sage is ... not so easy.  To some extent, on purpose.

Comment: I have tried this command line in python but it doesn't import `sage`.

Comment: Well, you have to do it inside of the *Sage* python, of course. Do `sage -ipython` and then `from sage.all import *`.  Again, I'm not saying this would work in your Cython example, but it might help you brainstorm.